# Student scores sorting help needed for Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class StudentScores {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the # of students");
    int numOfStudents = input.nextInt();
    int[] scores = new int[numOfStudents];
    String[] names = new String[numOfStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++) {
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        names[i] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter score: ");
        scores[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

                    // This doesn't sort anything, it just prints out the result in unsorted way
    /*for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + " " + scores[i]);
    }*/

    Arrays.sort(scores);
    reverse(scores);


    for (int u: scores) {
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}

   public static int[] reverse(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0, j = array.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    return array;
  }
 }
```

**The original question is:**
*Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of students, the students’ names, and their scores, and prints student names in decreasing order of their scores.*

**My question is** *how do you display the name with the sorted list of scores?*

You necessarily don't have to give me a complete solution, just give me a hint so I can solve it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate the related fields into a class, e.g. a `StudentRecord` can encapsulate the fields `name` and `score`.

Now, you sort a collection of these objects based on the second field, `score`. When it comes time to print the sorted result, you iterate through the collection and print the first field, `name`.

To illustrate:

```
public class StudentRecord implements Comparable<StudentRecord> {

    private String name;
    private int score;

    public StudentRecord(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentRecord other) {
        if (score == other.score) return 0;
        else if (score < other.score) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentRecord stu1 = new StudentRecord("Matt", 50);
        StudentRecord stu2 = new StudentRecord("John", 90);

        if (stu1.compareTo(stu2) == 0) {
            System.out.println(stu1.toString() + " has the same score with " + stu2.toString());
        }
        else if (stu1.compareTo(stu2) < 0) {
            System.out.println(stu1.toString() + " has a lower score than " + stu2.toString());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(stu1.toString() + " has a higher score than " + stu2.toString());
        }

        // output:
        // Matt has a lower score than John

    }

}
```

In many sorting algorithms, implementing the `Comparable` interface gives the algorithm enough information to sort a collection of such objects implementing said interface.

Comment: To sort them, you can make the class implement `Comparable` and implement `compareTo` properly (do not forget to reimplement `equals` and `hashCode`). Alternatively, use a `Comparator`.

Comment: Additionally, overriding the `toString` method would simplify the printing, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to use `Arrays.sort()` for this problem because you need to sort both arrays together. Write a sorting function that sorts the scores in order, and every time it swaps two scores, swap the students with those scores as well.

Comment: Yes! I was just trying to see the result, but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @Daniel: No, don't do that. Java is an OOP language. Use objects!